# Considerably "out"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

What is the meaning of the second sentence in the following paragraph?

> It is customary to give to the poor on the occasion of feasts, as might be expected. **Once I knew the sheikhs to be considerably out about the time of the feast of Barbara, and consequently of the subsequent feasts**. In the mountains to the south of us the fires were lit a day before the time.

Comment: As transcribed it’s gibberish.

Comment: Are you asking primarily about the word *out*?

Comment: Please use a more meaningful title. This title is almost identical to your other question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445377/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-second-sentence

Comment: I've edited your title to highlight what I think is the main phrase you're asking about. Feel free to [edit] further or to roll back the changes, especially if the new title doesn't capture the gist of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Without attempting to search out the original text for more context, I would have interpreted "out" here to be used in vaguely the same sense as it's used when discussing homosexuality.  That is, "out" means "making public" -- the fires were lit to make the impending event known.  Far more idiomatic, for the "in error" meaning, would be "off".

(Similar to "gay" in the sense of "happy", the use of "out" in the sense of "making public" used to be common, but it has languished after developing a bad "aura" from the homosexual connotation.)

However, on reading the other responses I can see that the "in error" meaning probably fits better.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are asking about the use of the word *out*, as opposed to anything about *senescence* (sic).

The sentence uses the word *out* in the following way:

> **out** *adjective*
>   (predicative) Mistaken; in error.
>   ‘he was slightly out in his calculations’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out)

The natural reading of the second 'sentence' you quote is a dangling clause that provides a reason for the phrase "as might be expected". The structure isn't what might be called a 'proper' subject-verb-object sentence, but it's sometimes used for rhetorical effect. *Like this*.

That is, once the author realised that the sheikhs were mistaken, the donating could be seen as a customary (and hence, expected) action.

Comment: OP's asking about the second sentence.

Comment: @AleksandrH That's what my answer addresses.

Answer (score 0):

As Lawrence pointed out, *out* here means 'mistaken; in error'.

So the final two sentences say that the sheiks were wrong about the timing of the fiests, and, as a consequence, the fires were lit a day too early.

Actually, another interpretation of the final sentence is possible: that the way the author came to know that the sheiks were mistaken was that he observed that the fires were lit a day too early.

In more detail, let us paraphrase the sentences

> Once I knew the sheikhs to be considerably out about the time of the feast of Barbara, and consequently of the subsequent feasts. In the mountains to the south of us the fires were lit a day before the time.

This may be paraphrased as

> It so happened one time that the sheikhs were quite mistaken about the timing of the feast of Barbara. They were therefore also mistaken about the timing of all the subsequent feast. **The sheikhs' mistake about the timing had the following consequence:** the fires that were supposed to be lit for the feast were in fact lit a day too early. These fires were in the mountains to the south of us.

The boldfaced clause is not the only possibility. It is possible that instead of it, the author meant to say this:

> **The reason I knew that the sheikhs were mistaken about the timing was this:**